# simple character replacement regex, tokenizing jsonpath

Tags: regex, typescript, jsonpath

I am trying to tokenize a jsonpath string. For example, given a string like the following:

`$.sensor.subsensor[0].foo[1][2].temp`

I want `["$", "sensor", "subsensor", "0", "foo", "1", "2", "temp"]`

I am terrible with regexs but I managed to come up with the following which according to regexr matches "." and "[" and "]". Assume the jsonpath string does not contain slices, wildcards, unions nor recursive descent.

`[\.\[\]]`

I am planning to match all "." and "[" and "]" chars and replace them with ";". Then i will split on ";".

The problem with the above regex is that I will get in certain instances ";;".

`$;sensor;subsensor;0;;foo;1;;2;;temp`

Is there a way I can in a single regex replace ".", "[", "]" as well as ".[" and "]." or "][" with ";"? Do I need to check for these groups explicitly or do I need to run the sequence through 2 regexs?

Comment: does the property always a string or number which doesn't contain `. or [ or ]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to omit `double semicolon`:

```js
console.log(
'$.sensor.subsensor[0].foo[1][2].temp'.replace(/[\.\[\]]+/g, ';')
)
```

Comment: I believe this is saying "match at least 1 of "[", "]", "." which would mean it also encompasses "][". "].", right? This is a good solution.

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Answer (score 2):

No needs to transform `.[]` into `;`, just split directly:

```js
console.log('$.sensor.subsensor[0].foo[1][2].temp'.split(/[.[\]]+/));
```

Comment: can you explain how this works? That regex doesn't look global and it's not escaping the "." or "[" character

Comment: @JeremyFisher: 1) The global flag is superfluous when spliting. 2) dot and openning square bracket don't need to be escaped within a character class. This is spliting on 1 or more any of `.`, `[` or `]`

Comment: This is really the best answer. Better if Toto's explanation were moved to the answer from the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Got a decent solution.

`/(\.|\].|\[)/g`

Apparently when you use `[]` as part of your regex that matches only a single character, which is why groups like "]." become ";;". Using `()` allows you to specify character groups, and the above group just enumerates the possibilities.